# React Controlled Component Sort Array with Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is a smallscale version of the project I'm trying to build:

```
import { useState,useEffect } from "react";

const Test = () => {

    const [myState, setMyState] = useState([
        {
            checked: false,
            type: "Cat",
            name: "Jasmine",
        },{
            checked: false,
            type: "Dog",
            name: "Toby",
        },{
            checked: false,
            type: "Dog",
            name: "Guster",
        },
    ])

    const [sortInfo,setSortInfo] = useState({
        sortDir: "asc",
        sortCol: "animal",
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        const sorted = [...myState].sort((a,b) => {
            if (sortInfo.sortDir === `asc`) {
                return a[sortInfo.sortCol] === b[sortInfo.sortCol] ? 0 : a[sortInfo.sortCol] < b[sortInfo.sortCol] ? -1 : 1
            } else {
                return a[sortInfo.sortCol] === b[sortInfo.sortCol] ? 0 : a[sortInfo.sortCol] < b[sortInfo.sortCol] ? 1 : -1
            }
        })
        setMyState(sorted)
    },[sortInfo])

    const sort = (sortBy) => {
        let sortCol
        if (sortBy === `Type`) {
            sortCol = [`type`]
        } else if (sortBy === `Name`) {
            sortCol = [`name`]
        }

        setSortInfo(prevState => {
            let newState = {...prevState}
            if (prevState.sortCol[0] === sortCol[0] && prevState.sortDir === `asc`) {
                newState.sortDir = `desc`
            } else {
                newState.sortDir = `asc`
            }
            newState.sortCol = sortCol
            return newState
        })
    }

    const checkAllBoxes = (e) => {
        //check all boxes
    }

    const checkOneBox = (e,animalToCheck) => {
        setMyState(prevState => {
            const newState = [...prevState]
            const foundAnimal = prevState.find(prev => prev.name === animalToCheck.name)
            foundAnimal.checked = !foundAnimal.checked
            return newState
        })
    }


    return (
        <main>
            <input onChange={(e) => {checkAllBoxes(e)}} type="checkbox"></input>
            <p onClick={(e) => {sort(e.target.innerText)}}>Type</p>
            <p onClick={(e) => {sort(e.target.innerText)}}>Name</p>

            {myState.map(animal => {
                return <div>
                    <input onChange={(e) => {checkOneBox(e, animal)}} checked={animal.checked} type="checkbox" ></input>
                    <p>{animal.type}</p>
                    <p>{animal.name}</p>
                </div>
            })}
        </main>
    )
}

export default Test
```

Having trouble with these controlled components. 2 Problems:

1. I want to be able to sort the state array and keep the checked boxes with the correct animal. I am having a lot of trouble with this.
2. I want to be able to check/uncheck all checkboxes by checking/unchecking the top box.
3. What else am I doing wrong and are there best practices I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not able to sort the array because:

1. You have set `sortCol: "animal"` but you have no key named as ***animal*** in `myState`. I believe you meant to sort by type so you should use `sortCol: "type"`.
2. Not sure why you have used array comparison when sortInfo.sortCol is a string, as per the initialization.

`prevState.sortCol[0] === sortCol[0]`

```
    if (sortBy === `Type`) {
       sortCol = [`type`]
    } else if (sortBy === `Name`) {
       sortCol = [`name`]
    }
```

3. Checkout [this article](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children) on the importance of using **key** attribute when creating a list of elements inside the array to achieve a stable identity.

You are not able to check/uncheck the box because:

1. There is a logical error in your code.

```
    const checkOneBox = (e,animalToCheck) => {
        setMyState(prevState => {
            const newState = [...prevState]
            const foundAnimal = prevState.find(prev => prev.name === animalToCheck.name)
            foundAnimal.checked = !foundAnimal.checked
            return newState
        })
    }
```

Here, you are returning a `newState` that is not modified. It is as same as the `prevState`.

2. For checking/unchecking all the boxes, you just have to update the state array with the checked value - `e.target.checked`.

[Check out the working code here.](https://codepen.io/Prakhathi/pen/rNdZYNV)